# Equation alignment "with offset"?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

With LaTeX, how do I achieve the following aligned equation?

[image]

Dashed lines indicate desired alignments. Solid boxes denote some random expressions.

Comment: You can use the `aligned` environment. Do you have a minimal example?

Comment: @Bernard, I didn't.  Because I had no idea how to do this.  But egreg's idea seems promising.

Comment: Egreg used aligned. You should take a look at `amsmath` documentation. Also `mathmode` is a comprehensive document about every possible layout problems for maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but here's the idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   & x^2y+xy(x+y)^6 \\
={}& \!\begin{aligned}[t]
       xy(   & x+x^6+6x^5y+15x^4y^2+20x^3y^3\\
       {}+{} & 15x^2y^4+6xy^5+y^6)
     \end{aligned}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you beat me by 8 seconds ;)

Comment: @runartrollet Maybe it's not the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    A&=&2+2&=4\\
    B&=&4\cdot2&=8\\
    &+4&&=12\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]